# crossbuild-essential-armel : unmet dependencies in Docker from debian:jessie

Tags: docker, dependencies, package, debian-jessie, cross-build

I have a docker container which I use to cross-compile applications for Debian-jessie. I had no problem with it since very recently but now it appears that I have unmet dependencies that I can not resolve :

`The following packages have unmet dependencies: crossbuild-essential-armel : 
Depends: gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi (>= 4.9.1-1) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: g++-arm-linux-gnueabi (>= 4.9.1-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

I tried to do it on others installations (VMs) but I have exactly the same results.

Below I paste the step of the build where the error appears :

```
Step 14 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --yes crossbuild-essential-armel
 ---> Running in b523b225cfdd
Hit http://emdebian.org jessie InRelease
Get:1 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [63.1 kB]
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie InRelease
Get:2 http://emdebian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [17.2 kB]
Get:3 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease [145 kB]
Get:4 http://emdebian.org jessie/main armel Packages [8215 B]
Hit http://httpredir.debian.org jessie Release.gpg
Get:5 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages [644 kB]
Hit http://httpredir.debian.org jessie Release
Get:6 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages [23.1 kB]
Get:7 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main armel Packages [626 kB]
Get:8 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/main armel Packages [23.7 kB]
Get:9 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [9064 kB]
Get:10 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie/main armel Packages [8868 kB]
Fetched 19.5 MB in 26s (747 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/httpredir.debian.org_debian_dists_jessie-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.gz is not what the server reported 23088 23096
W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/httpredir.debian.org_debian_dists_jessie-updates_main_binary-armel_Packages.gz is not what the server reported 23657 23707
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 crossbuild-essential-armel : Depends: gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi (>= 4.9.1-1) but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: g++-arm-linux-gnueabi (>= 4.9.1-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install --yes crossbuild-essential-armel' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

I find a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49515264/cross-compiling-debianjessie-container) with a similar problem but it was not very helpful for me. 
So my question is "How do I begin to correct this and make it works ?"

**Edit 1**

If it is relevant, it seems that the problem comes from the Debian Jessie distribution, I cannot get the crossbuild-essential-armel.

**Edit 2**

I tried to install the testing and unstable branch for the broken packages. They are installing but, after, the compilation still does not work.